# Problem with EF-Core Code first throwing error because of backing field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble getting my backing fields to work, i've tried my way through using this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field with no luck.

When i try to add the migration i'm greeted with this error:

The property 'Workflow._step1' is of type 'Step1' 
which is not supported by current database provider. 
Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property 
using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Multiple workflows can use the same step, so i want it to be saved like this

```
Workflow 
{
    Id,
    Step1Id
    Step2Id
}
```

Example that does not work code:

```
public class Workflow 
{
    private Step1 _step1;
    private Step2 _step2;

    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public bool Step1Enabled => true;
    public Step1 Step1 => Step1Enabled ? _step1 : null;

    public bool Step2Enabled => _step1.Completed;
    public Step2 Step2 => _step2Enabled ? _step2 : null;
}

public class Step1 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool StatusUniqueToStep1 { get; set; }
    public bool Completed {get; set; }
}

public class Step2 
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool StatusUniqueToStep2 { get; set; }
    public bool Completed {get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) :base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<Workflow> Workflows { get; set; }
    // Tried adding these, does not work.
    // public DbSet<Step1> Step1 { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<Step2> Step2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Tried adding these, does not work.
        // modelBuilder.Entity<Step1>();
        // modelBuilder.Entity<Step2>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
            .Property<Step1>("_step1");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
            .Property<Step2>("_step2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your database contain the Classes `Step1` and `Step2`?

Comment: Yes, but that was because of a previous migration. Desired result would be if EF creates everything as it normaly does as if the field was public.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to EF Core, but `OnModelCreating` sounds like it creates and entirely new Model deleting the old one

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the backing field with `HasField` - `Property<Step2>().HasField("_step2")`?  Also, have you added Step1 and Step2 types to the db configuration?  Given I cannot see them in the `OnModelCreating` I would assume not - do these types exist in the database table ie table named Step1?

Comment: Dont have an answer for that. but let's put it like this. If this was the Initial migration with an empty database it would throw the same errror. but i want EF to create the Step1 table and Step2 table as it normaly does. only difference is that i need it to use the backing-field instead of the public property.

Comment: @Andez Yes, i have tried everything that is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field

Comment: Try adding this line at the top: `modelBuilder.Entity<Step1>();`

Comment: At the end, what is `Step1` and `Step2` type? Please update the post with code that at least compiles.

Comment: Your example that does work is better anyway IMO. I feel like you have introduced business logic into your data with the latter; if it were me I would use the first.

Comment: As @MichaelPuckettII points out, although I cannot find the working code example he's referring, it seems like you're adding Business Logic to your Model classes which could be put in another class making it simpler

Comment: @MindSwipe I don't see the working example either... I interpreted the enum as a model in my non-coffee'd mind.  :/  However; the enum is closer to making a prettier model :P.

Comment: @MindSwipe And as I check again; that's not even an enum just an example..  I'm going back to bed.

Comment: Well for that i would need to introduce a new layer under the domain layer which i really do not have time to do. or dumb down the domain objects and introduce a layer between the domain and application layer to handle that logic, which is also very time consuming. it feels that it should be so uncommon for EF to store from a backing-field instead of a public property.

Comment: @EmilEkman have you tried adding the code I pointed out in a comment? If so what were the Results? Code for reference: `modelBuilder.Entity<Step1>();`

Comment: @MindSwipe yes, i updated the example with some of the suggested code. the result have been the same error stated in the post every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the case. By EF Core terminology these are not properties, but navigation properties, so they cannot be configured with `Property` fluent API (and in general are not returned by any metadata/entry method having `Property` / `Properties` in the name).

Instead, they are configured through relationship related fluent APIs. The problem with mapping the backing field though is that there is no natural fluent API for that similar to "properties", so you have to use directly the metadata.

The configuration could be like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step1)
    .WithMany()
    .Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetField("_step1");

modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step2)
    .WithMany()
    .Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetField("_step2");
```

or taking into account that the backing field names follow one of the EF Core naming conventions:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step1)
    .WithMany()
    .Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step2)
    .WithMany()
    .Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

But this is also the EF Core default behavior. So the actual problem is not the backing field, but the fact that EF Core by default does not include *read only* (no setter) properties (simple or navigation, doesn't matter). Hence the minimal configuration to make this work is like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step1);

modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Step2);
```

---

**Update:** In order to force EF Core to use the backing field for both `set` (when reading from database) and `get` (change tracking, storing to database), use the second configuration - with `.Metadata.DependentToPrincipal.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field)`.